# Cannot bind wxCommandEvent to a handler, invalid conversion from wxCommandEvent* to wxEvent*

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I ran into a strange issue when using wxWidgets 3.1.5. Trying to bind `wxCommandEvent` to a handler fails with the following compiliation error:

```
/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/wx/event.h:423:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘wxEventFunctorMethod<int, MainWindowPresenter, wxCommandEvent, MainWindowPresenter>::EventClass*’ {aka ‘wxEvent*’} to ‘wxCommandEvent*’ [-fpermissive]
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html), binding `wxCommandEvent` to a handler is explicitly mentioned. Here's the signature of the [Bind](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a03cc68ca201fb79c7e837919025be71a) method, I'm really sure what is wrong here:

```
void MainWindow::addEventHandler(const std::string& windowName, const wxEventType eventType,
                                 void (MainWindowPresenter::*callback)(wxCommandEvent&), MainWindowPresenter &handler) {
    auto widget = findWindowByName<wxWindow>(windowName);
    widget->Bind(eventType, callback, &handler);
}

void MainWindow::registerEventHandlers(MainWindowPresenter& handler) {
    addEventHandler("readersListBox", wxEVT_LISTBOX, &MainWindowPresenter::onReaderSelected, handler);
}
```

Handler is obviously a member method accepting `wxCommandEvent` reference:

```
void onReaderSelected(wxCommandEvent& event);
```

Curiously, it works fine for other `wxEvent` subtypes. Why doesn't this compile?

Comment: is this the real code you posted? What value is `eventType` holds? Also you don't have to register the `wxEVT_LISTBOX` - it is already registered? And if it's not your real code - please post the actual code that produces the error.

Comment: It also might be that the compiler doesn't know whether the `widget` is actually a `listbox` or not and so gives you an error. Do you not keep the pointer to the actual window somewhere in the class definition?

Comment: This is the actual code I wrote, the relevant parts anyway. `eventType` is `wxEVT_LISTBOX` (i.e. some int). I'm not sure what do you mean by saying that `wxEVT_LISTBOX` is already registered, I'm trying to react to an item getting selected in List box widget.

Explicitly casting `widget` to `wxListBox` does not solve the issue, nor does it produce other errors.

Comment: what I mean is - you don't have to call `addEventHandler()` and so `registerEventHandler()` will become obsolete. You also over complicate things a lot. PLease see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In order to react to the selection in the list box all you need to do is the following:

```
class MainWindow : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainWindow();
protected:
    void OnItemSelect(wxCommandEvent &event);
private:
    wxListBox *widget;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow() : wxFrame(...)
{
    widget = new wxListBox( this, wxID_ANY, /* rest of the parameters */);
    widget->Bind( wxEVT_LISTBOX, &MainWindow::OnItemSelect, this );
}

void MainWindow::OnItemSelect(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
// react on item selection
}
```

It can't be simpler than this.

Now you can choose to create the listbox as not a member. Buit then you need to ensure that the widget type is wxListBox by using either `dynamic_cast<>()` or `wxDynamicCast()` and then call `Bind()` on casted pointer.

Something like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : wxFrame()
{
    auto widget = wxDynamicCast( findWindowByName<wxWindow>(windowName), wxListBox );
    if( widget )
        widget->Bind( wxEVT_LISTBOX, &MainWindow::OnItemSelect, this );
}
```

BTW, I hope you have an appropriate `findWindowByName<>` function, as all wx calls are using Capital letters in the beginning.

Also, make sure to not to use the smart pointer to create controls and main frame. wxWidgets is designed in 1990 when smart pointers were not used and so if you do you will get a crash, because the destructor of the windows will destroy all of its children automatically, but will not NULL-ify the pointer and so you will get a crash.

Comment: I think there is some kind of misunderstanding here. The snippet I posted is from a much larger application implementing [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern. `registerEventHandlers` is a single point where all widgets get bound to presenter, but I have reduced it to a single line for clarity.  The issue is not in `registerEventHandler`, the code does not compile because of `Bind` call in `addEventHandler`, and I would like to understand why.

Comment: @Doom8890, look at my `Bind()` call and look what you are trying to compile very carefully. Then fix you syntax.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to register the event again - it is already registered and so you can drop the call to registerEventHandler. It is un-needed and useless - you will have 2 events registered, which is wrong. Just try it.

Comment: What is your point exactly? I'm looking for an answer as to why my code does not compile. While I'm sure it works fine, your answer is not relevant as it does not answer my question, nor does it fit the architecture of my application. Additionally, there is no duplicate binding (not the issue anyway). For each widget in the view, registerEventHandler calls addEventHandler which in turn calls Bind.

Comment: @Doom8890,   Your code - `widget->Bind(eventType, callback, &handler);`. My code - `widget->Bind( wxEVT_LISTBOX, &MainWindow::OnItemSelect, this );` Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Doom8890, also I don't see it ensuring that the window you binding the event to is actually of the proper type. While my code guarantees it. Just imagine what happen if a button will receive EVT_LISTBOX?

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now, although I do not quite understand it, but maybe because it's super past midnight here. For whatever reason I was under the impression that wxEventType is parent of wxEvent, but it is not, and since compiler didn't complain up until the static_cast, I thought nothing of it. Maybe you can clarify this or wxEventTypeTag mapping for future readers and I will accept the answer.

In any case, changing parameter type from wxEventType to wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent> solves the issue, but I'm too tired now to go into details.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

`Bind()` is a template function using the event type (its first argument) to verify that the event handler provided is actually compatible with it by using `wxEventTypeTag<>` specialization for the given event type. In your case you're just passing a generic `wxEventType` to it, which makes this check fail.

The simplest solution is probably to make your `addEventHandler()` a template function too. If this is impossible or undesirable, you can use a different `Bind()` overload, e.g. the one taking the arbitrary functor should work.